# why does following printf print 0x32

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
printf("%#04x",50);
}
```

Some one showed me above code and I could not understand it since I do have used printf in C programs but above sort of use I saw in my life for the first time.
Why did above code prints output as

```
0x32
```

Can some one give me a link or reference to some thing so that I can understand it better.

Comment: It would have helped if you had indicated what you expect to see instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `printf(3)` manual page:

## The flag characters

The character % is followed by zero or more of the following flags:

# — The value should be converted to an  "alternate  form".   For  o conversions,  the  first  character of the output string is made zero (by prefixing a 0 if it was not zero already).  For x and X conversions, a nonzero result has the string "0x" (or "0X" for X conversions) prepended to it.  For a, A, e, E, f, F,  g,  and  G conversions,  the  result  will  always contain a decimal point, even if no digits follow it (normally, a decimal  point  appears in  the  results  of those conversions only if a digit follows). For g and G conversions, trailing zeros are not removed from the result  as  they would otherwise be.  For other conversions, the result is undefined.

Other flags omitted...

Thus, %# prepends "0x" to the output since the output format is `x`. The 0 is there to use `0` (zeros) for padding. Then the number 4 says the total number of characters to print is four. Had the number 4 been exchanged with 10, the output would have been `0x00000032` – a total of 10 characters.

Comment: 0 is not part of the flag to prepend `0x`. It specified padding with zeros instead of spaces. In this example it ends up being irrelevant because there is no padding.

Comment: Thanks! I think I fixed it now. There is padding _defined_ (the `4`), but indeed no padding in the end result, since the number 32 + "0x" gives 4 characters total.

Answer (score 5):

50 decimal is 32 hexadecimal.

Apart from that, the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) should tell you all you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

Because %x formats the given value into hexadecimal.

In facts, 0x32 (hex) == 50 (decimal).

This is a good [primer](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/format_specs.html) for reference.